# An docker container in Azure Pipelines of an API (DRF) fails to access secondary DB SQL-SERVER only in unittesting

Tags: sql-server, api, docker, django-rest-framework, azure-devops

In my dev and production environment a dockerized DRF-API runs well. But when this very same code is built in Azure Pipelines for CI/CD, the container fails to establish connection to the SQL-SERVER which is used to query data (no primary DB of API) in the TEST step.

AzPipeline step to build the container:

```
- task: Docker@2
inputs:
  command: build
  Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
  containerRegistry: reg
  repository: $(repo)
  tags: $(imageTag)
displayName: 'Build Docker'
```

AzPipeline to run the container and the test:

```
- script: |
  docker run --name $(test_container) -p 8000:8000 $(name)/$(name2):dev &
  docker start $(test_container)
  sleep 10
  docker exec $(test_container) python src/manage.py test myapp --no-input --verbosity=3
```

I get the error:

```
    Adding permission 'Permission object (49)
    Adding permission 'Permission object (50)
    Adding permission 'Permission object (51)
    Adding permission 'Permission object (52)
    Creating test database for alias 'my_sql_server' ('test_my_SQL_DB')...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
        self.connect()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
        self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 307, in get_new_connection
        timeout=timeout)
    pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I used this image for the Docker file:

```
FROM  nickgryg/alpine-pandas:latest
```

This is the configuration for the ODBC:

```
    [FreeTDS]
    Description=FreeTDS Driver
    Driver=/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
    TDS_Version=7.4
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to add following entry in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`

```
 [<sql details>]
    host = <host of the sql server>
    port = <port of the sql server>
    tds version = 7.4
```